# ConEmu Solarized color scheme not displaying properly in vim

Tags: vim, colors, conemu, solarized

I'll like to use vim terminal in ConEmu with Solarized color scheme. After configuring ConEmu and vimrc, some of the text from the help file is unreadable as shown below.

[image: vim screenshot]
My vimrc:

```
runtime bundle/vim-pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

let g:solarized_termtrans = 1
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized

set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab
```

My ConEmu settings:

[image: ConEmu settings]

Comment: I believe, smth is wrong with your vim config. It draw text with both background and foreground with #4 color. You may show real console (Ctrl+Win+Alt+Space) to ensure that text is unreadable there too.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that this is a vim/solarized/cmd related problem. Instead of changing the ConEmu color settings, I can resolve this by adding this to my vimrc:

`let g:solarized_underline=0`